# In PostgreSQL, which types can be cast with the type name first?

Tags: postgresql, select

Reading the PostgreSQL docs, I see that you can cast a longish bit of text to xml like this:

```
SELECT xml '<long>long text, may span many lines</long>'
```

[SELECT xml '...'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-xml.html)

Curious, I found that I could do the same with JSON:

```
SELECT json '{"arg1":"val1", <more args spanning many lines>}'
```

(I couldn't find an official reference for this one.  It just works!)

By contrast, this does not work:

```
SELECT float8 3.14159
```

I like this alternate syntax from a readability perspective.  Now I'm looking for a reference listing which types may be specified *up front* like this. but I haven't found it yet.

Any pointers?

Comment: [Type casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) in the Postgres manual

Comment: This does not have what I'm looking for.  Neither does it list the "typename value" syntax, except as a function call.  e.g. `select float8 3.14159` fails for me with *ERROR: syntax error at or near "3.14159"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) says:

> A constant of an *arbitrary* type can be entered using any one of the following notations:
>
> `type 'string'`
>   `'string'::type`
>   `CAST ( 'string' AS type )`
>
> The string constant's text is passed to the input conversion routine for the type called `type`. The result is a constant of the indicated type. The explicit type cast can be omitted if there is no ambiguity as to the type the constant must be (for example, when it is assigned directly to a table column), in which case it is automatically coerced.

The form you are asking about is the first one.

So this can be used for all PostgreSQL types.

Note that the data *must* be specified as a string literal (in single or dollar quotes) when you use that syntax.

Comment: Even complex types are possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=669a3e137b63d5f80c3ab4be495534b1

Comment: Ah yes!  I was missing the string requirement.  thanks!

Comment: Just learned that arbitrary doesn't include array types.  `select  int[] '{1,2,3}'` fails but `select  '{1,2,3}'::int[], cast('{4,5,6}' as int[])` both work

Comment: Try  "select float8 (3.14159)"

Comment: Try `SELECT _int4 '{1,2,3}';`.